# How to save average values of column in a csv?

Tags: python

```
a=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/D/FIELD-3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TOp']['data'])
a=(a.flatten(order='C'))
a.shape(3,1000)
```

How could i get the average value of each column in a written in a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [np.average](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) with the axis attribute:

```
np.average(a, axis=0)
```